# Create front end post option with php in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I made a custom post type in WordPress which can be submitted by guest. I am trying to create a page in WordPress where guest can submit this post.
In post there is title, dropdown, text area etc are.
Can anyone help me to create this page? I needs to do this page in php without any plugin.

Comment: This is too broad, unfortunately. You have to try something first, SO is not a collaboration site, it's to help solve tangible issues. Git Hub is more for collaboration.

Answer (score 0):

to create page you need to create post template in particular theme and then show your posts you created from frontend

Comment: Hi, 
Thanks for your reply.
I need to add a form with all fields in post. 
Page I already have created.
Regards